# Parent Component State Array does not update properly

Tags: reactjs, components, state, parent-child, parent

I am building a game on React.
The first part is an array which is a state defined this way:

```
const [mainBoard, setMainBoard] = useState(
    new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
  );
```

Then I create a second array.

```
const [miniBoard, setMiniBoard] = useState(
    new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
  );
```

The first array is looped which renders the items of the second array.

Example:
If the miniBoard array is changed and it meets a specific criteria the parent array needs to be updated. When the parent array changes then child array's behavior should change, but parent array is not updating properly.

This is the function that I use to make the change in the mainBoard.

```
  const handleMainBoardChange = (currentIndex, currentTurn) => {
    console.log("handleMainBoardChange ", currentIndex, currentTurn);
    const updatedmainBoard = {
      ...mainBoard[currentIndex],
      val: currentTurn,
      disabled: true,
    };
    console.log(updatedmainBoard);
    const newmainBoard = mainBoard.slice();
    newmainBoard[currentIndex] = updatedmainBoard;
    console.log(newmainBoard);
    setMainBoard(newmainBoard);
  };
```

Until the 2nd last line, the console.log shows fine but the mainboard state is not updated. The weird thing is, it updates properly the 1st time but the 2nd time it doesn't. It consoles the update but doesn't actually update the state.

What am I doing wrong with updating the MainBoard array that it is not updating properly?

My current layout is:

First Component runs the loop on the MainBoard which displays 9 items.
Each loop iteration displays the MiniBoard component, which also runs a loop on the MiniBoard and displays 9 items.

I pass the handleMainBoardChange function to the MiniBoard component, which is called when the specific criteria is met. That is working.

> UPDATE: Based on the answer, I updated my code with this but that still didn't work.

```
  const handleMainBoardChange = (currentIndex, currentTurn) => {
    const updatedNewMainBoard = mainBoard.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === currentIndex) {
        return { val: currentTurn, disabled: true };
      }
      return item;
    });
    console.log(updatedNewMainBoard);
    setMainBoard(updatedNewMainBoard);
  };
```

[Here is a screenshot of the console for help,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Ont.png)

Line 143, shows that it correctly saw the criteria where the main board needed to change.
In the first part, on line 267, you see that x was recorded in index 1. But in the second part of the console, on line 267, you see that it was overwritten by the previous state. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator (...) creates a 'shallow' copy of the mainBoard array, but the elements of the array are objects. Shallow copying an array of objects only creates a new array with references those objects... So when you modify an object in the new array, it actually modifies the original object.
One solution is to create a 'deep' copy of the mainBoard array, including its elements, so that each object is also copied.
The map method iterates over the mainBoard array and creates a new array with updated objects:

```
const [mainBoard, setMainBoard] = useState(
  new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
);

const [newMainBoard, setNewMainBoard] = useState(
  new Array(9).fill({ val: null, disabled: false })
);

const handleMainBoardChange = (currentIndex, currentTurn) => {
  const updatedNewMainBoard = newMainBoard.map((item, index) => {
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      return { val: currentTurn, disabled: true };
    }
    return item;
  });
  setNewMainBoard(updatedNewMainBoard);
};
```

For the state variables, each one is arrays of 9 objects. The second one should use newMainBoard and setNewMainBoard.

In handleMainBoardChange, item represents each element of the array during the loop. Inside the map callback function, you can access and modify props of item.
In the map callback, it checks if the current `index` matches the `currentIndex` parameter passed to handleMainBoardChange. If there's a match, it returns a new object with updated values for val. Otherwise, it returns the original item object.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it still didn't solve the issue.
Furthermore, the 2nd array does not need changing, currently I only need to update the MainBoard, I don't need a newMainBoard state. I will update my question in more detail.